# GNU screen - cannot enter command mode in a Putty session

Tags: putty, gnu-screen

Opening a shell session on a Linux Red-Hat 5 system, using Putty over ssh, I launch a screen session, but I find that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> that I do not see the command prompt. All other screen commands work fine, apart from this one.

This appears to me to be a problem specific to the combination of Putty and screen, as it worked with other terminal emulators. Has anybody else come across this?

Comment: OK it turned out there some very strange tty settings going on. Setting a "sane" config and the key combinations work as expected.

Regards
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Putty you can enter screen command prompt by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>